# Parsed KML file doesn't show route in Google Map in my App

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am successfully parsed KML file from server and also from assets folder and get co-ordinates from KML file and able to display route from server side KML file.

But the problem for test I have download KML file for route between two location from Google map and put KML file in assets folder and accessing it. It successfully parsed and i got coordinates in log also but i can't able to display route on map using that co-ordinates.. So can anybody tell that can't we display route from downloaded KML file from google map. For test i have checked if that downloaded KML file is valid or not and I came to know its a valid KML file.

I am parsing my KML file using SAXParser.

Comment: You can. Why not? give more details...

Comment: I did. I able to display route using server KML file from WS but for my test i have downloaded KML file using co-ordinates of near by my area. But i couldn't show route

Comment: bur for that you need to again re draw the routes...

Comment: Your question makes no sense as you state that you can successfully parse coordinates from all sort of kml files.

Comment: @greenapps Just make sense for you to read question carefully. I have printed co-ordinates from parsed KML file in Log. But I couldn't able to draw route using that co-ordinates

Comment: @MD But why i able to get co-ordinates from other KML file. then wht it need draw again.

Comment: `But I couldn't able to draw route using that co-ordinates` Yes. That is what i understood. Then don't blame the kml file as that will not try to show a route. You are trying to show a route from coordinates and you fail.

Comment: @greenapps But that KML file i have downloaded from Google Map. So in Google map it shows a route but in my app route doesn't display.

Comment: Apparently you do something wrong. We dont know how you extract the coordinates from it. And we dont know how you try to put those coordinates on a map. So how do you think we could tell you what goes wrong?

Comment: Post your co-ordinates mapping to gmap code

Comment: @greenapps Wanna a code???

Comment: Please fullfill the request of @RIT.

Comment: Yes post related code

Comment: You didn't post url for mapping above co-ordinates

Comment: see this url https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Seema+Hall,+Anandnagar+Rd,+Ahmedabad,+Gujarat+380015/AlphaOne+Shopping+Mall,+Ahmedabad,+Gujarat/@23.0264585,72.5103879,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x395e9b2ad60cb03d:0x764f6e2d460dfea3!2m2!1d72.519836!2d23.013377!1m5!1m1!1s0x395e84b659183b6b:0xe143f5c926e0efad!2m2!1d72.53139!2d23.03979?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have spent 2 days for this Finally I got solution.

In my `KML` file I was using `XML schema` as

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

So i have just replace as

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

only and also add

```
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
```

tag in `<PlaceMark>` tag.