# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment' android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android just trying implement Google maps in my application.I refer this tutorial
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

I followed all the steps very carefully, I got exception and error:

> "Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'
>   android.view.InflateException"

I searched for solution, found this question: [Could Not Find Class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839336/could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-maps-supportmapfragment)

It seems he is also having same problem, I tried all the solutions given under above link. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Below is required LogCat output:

> 10-27 16:52:48.906: E/Trace(13150): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 10-27 16:52:48.951: E/dalvikvm(13150): Could not
>   find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment',
>   referenced from method
>   com.triodoxic.googlemaptest.MainActivity.onCreate 10-27 16:52:49.046:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-27 16:52:49.046:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.triodoxic.googlemaptest/com.triodoxic.googlemaptest.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class fragment 10-27 16:52:49.046: E/AndroidRuntime(13150):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2196)
>   10-27 16:52:49.046: E/AndroidRuntime(13150):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
>   10-27 16:52:49.046: E/AndroidRuntime(13150):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149) 10-27
>   16:52:49.046: E/AndroidRuntime(13150):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
>   10-27 16:52:49.046: E/AndroidRuntime(13150):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: Have you referenced the library project properly

Comment: show ur xml `Layout`

Comment: Yes , Both appcompact and google-playservice-lib are properly referenced.

Comment: <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

Comment: @Raghunandan can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886749/parsed-kml-file-doesnt-show-route-in-google-map-in-my-app?

Answer (score 0):

**Be Careful, Follow these steps and save your time**

Right Click on your Project Explorer.

Select New-> Project -> Android Application Project from Existing Code

Browse upto this path only - "C:\Users**your path**\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"

Be careful brose only upto - google_play_services and not upto google_play_services_lib

And this way you are able to import the google play service lib.

Let me know if you have any queries regarding the same.

Thanks

Comment: should i delete my previous library  google_play_services_lib from workspace?

Comment: Yes. You should and after that try out these steps. It will work for you. sure